# Mysql ranking data to HTML table on site

Tags: html, mysql, web, html-table, ranking

I have setup my own server for a multiplayer pvp game 3 days ago, I am using a plugin that allows players to earn points in the server and stores everything in a MySQL database which I have full access to.

Yesterday I started working on a website for my server and I came up with an idea to make the points system more interesting for the players, I want to make a table on my website that extracts the top 10 players from my database and puts them into a HTML table.

I tried searching for this online, but found answers that only allowed me to extract all players or sort them by name etc, I just need the top 10 with the highest value in the column "points".

The database table name is "ranks" the column with the names is "lastDisplayName" and the column with points is called "points"

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me find a way to put this in a table that sais Rank, Name and points.

Sadly I can't upload the picture to show what my table would look like.

Comment: Do you need help with the web development for your table or do you just need the SQL statement?

Comment: I want to make a HTML code that extracts the data needed from my database, this means I will first need the mysql connection thingy where I can fill in my username password table name etc. Then I need the SQL statement I guess the one suggested does what I need

SELECT DISTINCT lastDisplayName FROM ranks ORDER BY `points` DESC LIMIT 10;

Then I need the part where it is turned into an actual table

Comment: That means I need help with the web development I guess

Comment: I think you need to sit down with a decent beginner's book or tutorial (but I also think you know this already)

Comment: Yeah, I do, however that is the only thing I want to make regarding extracting information. Nothing more really.

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below

```
  SELECT DISTINCT lastDisplayName FROM ranks ORDER BY `points` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the query, but first I need the code to connect to my database before I can give it the query right? Also, how do I get the data retreived with your query into a table?

Comment: Code to connect to DB, code to run a query, code to parse the result, code to build a table... you are asking people to do a lot of work for you.